# Different content type objects in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-contenttypes

I am having a hard time to understand ContentType. I am learning from a tutorial, this is the [link](http://ryanberg.net/blog/2008/jun/24/basics-creating-tumblelog-django/). I have synced the database, and its working in the admin. But when I try to load the ContentType objects in the template, I get nothing. When I see the page source, the `get_rendered_method` is not loading the rendered template in the homepage.html.

These are my models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    photo_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'
        ordering = ['-photo_upload']

class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class StreamItem(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    # The get_rendered_html method simply passes the retrieved object to a template with that object’s name
    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = 'stream_item_%s.html' % (self.content_type.name)
        return render(request, template_name, {'object':self.content_object})
```

These are the template for content_type.name:

stream_item_Photo.html:

```
<div class="si">
    <img src="{{ object.image }}">
    <p>{{ object.pub_date|date:"F jS Y, P" }}</p>
    <p>{{ object.user }}</p>
</div>
```

stream_item_Status.html:

```
<div class="si">
    <p>{{ object.state }}</p>
    <p>{{ object.time|date:"F jS Y, P" }}</p>
    <p>User: {{ object.user }}</p>
</div>
```

Where am I doing the mistake? How do I load different content_type objects in the template? I would really appreciate if you could help me solve this. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I call the `get_rendered_html` in the homepage.html. This is homepage.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      {% for stream_item in stream_item_list %}
          <div class="col-md-4">
              {{ stream_item.get_rendered_html }}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you call get_rendered_html?

Comment: @Jay I call it in the homepage. I have updated the question. Please have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `render` you use in `get_rendered_html` actually does not return a string or anything you can directly use in your template, it returns a `HttpResponse` object. A `HttpResponse` object basically consists of the rendered template and Http headers.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class StreamItem(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_rendered_html(self):
        template_name = 'stream_item_%s.html' % self.content_type.name
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(template_name, {'object': self.content_object}))
```

`render_to_string` does the same as `render`, except it returns just a string containing the rendered template, without any header information. `mark_safe` marks the string as safe for direct use in the template. Without it, any html tags in the string would be escaped upon use in the homepage template.

Comment: Hi! I imported `render_to_strings` and `mark_safe` in the models.py. And updated the `get_rendered_html` method as you told me. But, its still not showing anything. What maybe the cause now?

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does it just not render? Have you made sure if stream_item_list actually contains values?

Comment: Yup! You are right. There's nothing in it!!! But I am not getting any errors either...

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to know if this way of calling template is ok for production with lots of photos and status? Or is it better to load the `si` `StreamItem` instances in the homepage and do some `if else`? Please, give me your suggesetion and also add it in you answer. Thank you again!

Comment: @Robin This method is perfectly fine for production. Both methods iterate over `stream_item_list` once and parse some strings into the file. There isn't any significant advantage for either one of those methods.  If 'lots' realy is a lot and you want to include all items, take a look at [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) if you haven't already. That's good practice regardless of the method used for display.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your generous help! :D